# How can I store a value and make it available throughout a "request" with or without an HttpContext?

Tags: c#, .net-core

In a scenario where my application maybe serving both HTTP requests and also doing work in the background (no http context), how do I make a value globally available through the entire request when I don't necessarily have the ability to pass that value from handler to handler?

### Example 1: (http, solved)

A request comes in as an HTTP request so there's an http context. This request has some headers that I'll need not only for processing the request, but I'll also have to forward any trace IDs from those headers on to any downstream service requests. That's not a problem because I can access the HttpContext from anywhere in the flow. My logger can add it to logs, but my named HTTP clients can also be setup with a custom handler to always access those headers from the original request so that it can update them and keep the trace going.

### Example 2: (not http)

That same application might also have a message bus consumer running, so there's no HTTP context when it picks up a message to process. Instead, it looks at the message payload or headers to find these trace IDs. Since the custom message handler for any outgoing request that occur as a result of this message depends on their being an original http context from which it would get those trace IDs, this no longer works as it will always be null.

I need some way to store values that are scoped to the "request" whether it is http or not and they need to be accessible globally as there are situations where I cannot pass the value (e.g. items that are setup during startup like logging).

My first thought was to use a scoped service registered in DI. I would call it `FooContext` and maybe it has methods on it that allow me to update it's internal values. Then anywhere else in the application where I could request `FooContext` should receive a scoped copy along with the current state for that request. I've had mixed results with this:

To test, I spun up two threads that each got it's own service scope. Assume that I have a registered scoped service for `FooContext` that returns a new instance each time it is requested. Usage would be something like this:

```cs
var thread1 = new ThreadStart(() => {
  var serviceScope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope().ServiceProvider;
  var context = serviceScope.GetService<FooContext>();
  context.AddValue("some", "thing");
});

var thread2 = new ThreadStart(() => {
  var serviceScope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope().ServiceProvider;
  var context = serviceScope.GetService<FooContext>();
  context.AddValue("some", "other value");
});
```

On the first couple runs, it looked like each thread had it's own instance of `FooContext` but then eventually, I started to see some crossover. Now I realize Threads don't necessarily equal "Requests", but it was the only way I could think of to separate the service scopes. I'm open to other ways to test.

Is there a better way to do this? Open to other ideas as well. TIA

Comment: One option might be to have a class that is registered as `InstancePerLifetimeScope` (in Autofac parlance). If you get your lifetime scopes set up correctly in terms of processing the message bus (e.g. you may need to create a new lifetime scope pre message processed), then it will work both in web and message processing contexts.

Comment: Your underlying problem is to support trace IDs? `AsyncLocal` _may_ be worth looking into.

Comment: @mjwills - Yeah that's what "Scoped" is in MSDI parlance. I was having mixed results with that but I think I may have just found out why that is - problem with the implementation of a different package. It might actually still be the right answer. As for `AsyncLocal` I was looking into that... still trying to wrap my head around it vs. `ThreadLocal` and how I would use it in this context.